# SQL Merge Statement - Output into a scalar variable (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting my head around the MERGE statement in SQL server. I generally use it to insert/update a single row, which I realise isn't the only use, but it's something I seem to do quite often.

But what happens if you want to insert a value of 1, or update to increment the value and output the incremented value eg:

```
CREATE TABLE [Counter] (
  [Key] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Value] INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @paramKey VARCHAR(255);

SET @paramKey = 'String';

MERGE [Counter] AS targt
USING (Values(@paramKey)) AS source ([Key])
ON (targt.[Key] = source.[Key])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Value = Value +1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Key], Value)
    VALUES (source.[Key], 1);

-- but now I want the new value!
```

Is there a way of doing this? I notice the output clause in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510625.aspx but it doesn't seem to work with scalars (I could output to a single row-ed table variable but that seems wrong):

```
-- using table variables but seems 
DECLARE @paramKey VARCHAR(255), @value int;

SET @paramKey = 'String'

DECLARE @Tab table (
    [Value] INT
)

MERGE Counter AS targt
USING (Values(@paramKey)) AS source ([Key])
ON (targt.[Key] = source.[Key])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Value = Value +1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Key], Value)
    VALUES (source.[Key], 1)
    OUTPUT inserted.[Value] INTO @Tab;

-- can now use @Tab as a single rowed table variable
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: No there is not a better option. The way you have suggested with a table variable is the standard way to deal with this.